# Pure python ping is causing my Zyxel router to trigger bad-icmp-l4-size ATTACK warning

Tags: python, ping, icmp

I'm using pure Python ping utility from ftp://ftp.visi.com/disk3/mdc/ping.py to monitor hosts across the network and my ZyWALL USG200 router is complaining like this:

`from Any to DMZ, [type=ICMP-Decoder(8911017)] bad-icmp-l4-size ATTACK bad-icmp-l4-size Action: No Action Severity: medium`

What could be wrong?

UPD: I'll try to capture actual packets via USG's maintenance menu and compare with Linux ping...

Comment: it involves pure ping programming of the mentioned python implementation, the evidence is how it breaks router monitoring. Answer contains software fix for the mentioned implementation of ping which is also about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've copied ping packet contents from WireShark analysis of captured packets - code had it as 192 letters Q, ping had it bit differently:

replace or insert after line 128

`data = 192 * 'Q'`

the correct definition of packet contents

`data = 'e283030000000000101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f202122232425262728292a2b2c2d2e2f3031323334353637'.decode("hex")`

and warnings went away.

But indeed I may want to look for cleaner implementation as José suggests.

Answer (score 2):

According to the warning of your router, looks like the ICMP packet is not well formed. Particularly, the size of the layer 4 (ICMP) of the packet seems to be wrong (`bad-icmp-l4-size`).

You should use something like `tcpdump` to get the content of the sent package, using something like:

```
sudo tcpdump -nnvXS -c1 icmp
```

In your situation, I'd rather look for another implementation. That code is a mess.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip and command example! I've compared packets, after mocking "ping" it seemed to go away - will write in answer.